# GPS "turn on" different sentences

Tags: unix, gps

How can I write to a serial port in Unix? I have a gps puck that is connected via USB and shows up in my linux mint's directory tree under `/dev/ttyUSB0`. I have tried a number of things to write to it without much luck.

My end goal is to write a gps sentence to it and have the gps's GLL statement turned on. The [website](http://www.usglobalsat.com/store/gpsfacts/bu353s4_gps_facts.html) (for my bu-353) says this: `Enable GLL Output 1sec - $PSRF103,1,0,1,1*24`, so I though I could just do `echo -e "$PSRF103,1,0,1,1*24\r" > /dev/ttyUSB0` and that would turn it on, but that doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to write to a serial port for a gps puck and have it turn on a specific sentence if you "pass" it the correct string (like the one above)? That would be very helpful.

For example, when I do `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 4800; echo -e "$PSRF103,1,0,1,1*24\r" > /dev/ttyUSB0; cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | grep -E "GLL|RMC";` I only get $GPRMC. How can I enable $GPGLL or another sentence?

Comment: Well thank you for down voting with no explanation. This isn't really anywhere on the internet, yet I have seen references to doing it without actually seeing how it's done. The gps's home page says that it can be done and gives the string to do so, however it simply doesn't work. I am sure it can be done and if you cannot provide an explanation as to why this question should not be posted and discussed then don't just down vote. Please don't just click the upside-down triangle just because you can - provide some feed back

Comment: I bet you just down voted because you don't know the answer to the question and you are angry. :D haha - right now I *really* wish that Stackoverflow gave the list of down-voters. Oh boy would they have some down votes from me; just kidding, but this is still really annoying.

Comment: I don't know why your question was down-voted, but I have a guess.  What you're really asking to do is write a string to a serial port.  If you ask that question and be specific as to what you want to do it with, you are much more likely to get an answer.  I think if you also search around for writing to a serial port in Python, Java, C, or C++ under Linux, you will find a lot of existing code.  If you want to do this with Bash, try posting over at SuperUser.com.

Comment: @Brad thanks for your response and probably the up vote. I guess I am simply confused as to how I should do this in general. I am relatively new to Unix and - although I can navigate and do things pretty well in the terminal - I simply don't know how to communicate with serial ports. I asked this question when I saw something else on stackoverflow that was very similar but didn't work for me. Thanks for the reference to superuser.com, though. I will have to try that out (if I don't find my question there already).

Comment: Yet another option would be to ask in http://electronics.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @heltonbiker This question is completely off-topic for the Electronics SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo -e "$PSRF103,1,0,1,1*24\r"
```

The problem with the above is that the shell will think that $PSRF103 is a shell variable, and attempt to expand it, which results in ",1,0,1,1*24\r" being sent to the serial port. Use single quotes instead of double quotes to preserves the literal value of each character in the string e.g. echo -e '$PSRF103,1,0,1,1*24\r'

Comment: I can't believe that was it. Thanks.